# Microsoft Charting - Make Y Axis Always Visible

Tags: charts, data-visualization, mschart

I am creating a Microsoft Chart in C#. It works fine but when there is no data the Y Axis disappears. I would like the Y Axis to be always visible. I tried to find a way to solve it but I wasn't able.

This is my code:

```
Chart chart = new Chart {
  AntiAliasing = AntiAliasingStyles.All,
  TextAntiAliasingQuality = TextAntiAliasingQuality.High,
  BackColor = Color.FromArgb(250, 250, 250),
  Height = size.Height,
  Width = size.Width
};

chart.Legends.Clear();

ChartArea area = new ChartArea {
  BackColor = Color.Transparent,
  BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(240, 240, 240),
  BorderWidth = 1,
  BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid,
  AxisX = new Axis {
    Enabled = AxisEnabled.True,
    IntervalAutoMode = IntervalAutoMode.VariableCount,
    IsLabelAutoFit = true,
    IsMarginVisible = true,
    LabelStyle = new LabelStyle { ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 100, 100), Font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular) },
    LineColor = Color.FromArgb(220, 220, 220),
    MajorGrid = new Grid { LineColor = Color.FromArgb(240, 240, 240), LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid },
    MajorTickMark = new TickMark { LineColor = Color.FromArgb(220, 220, 220), Size = 4.0f },
  },
  AxisY = new Axis {
    Enabled = AxisEnabled.True,
    IntervalAutoMode = IntervalAutoMode.VariableCount,
    IsLabelAutoFit = true,
    IsMarginVisible = true,
    LabelStyle = new LabelStyle { ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 100, 100), Font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular) },
    LineColor = Color.Transparent,
    MajorGrid = new Grid { LineColor = Color.FromArgb(240, 240, 240), LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid },
    MajorTickMark = new TickMark { LineColor = Color.FromArgb(240, 240, 240), Size = 2.0f }
  },
  Position = new ElementPosition { Height = 100, Width = 100, X = 0, Y = 0 }
};

chart.ChartAreas.Add(area);

area.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "H:mm";
area.AxisX.LabelStyle.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Hours;

Series series = new Series {
  CustomProperties = "PointWidth = 1",
  IsXValueIndexed = true,
  XValueType = (ChartValueType)Enum.Parse(typeof(ChartValueType), x.Data.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].Name)
};

series.BorderWidth = 2;
series.BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(84, 164, 232);
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Area;
series.Color = Color.FromArgb(222, 234, 244);

series.Points.DataBindXY(x.Data, s.Data);

chart.Series.Add(series);
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it is not possible.

As as work around you can add another a dummy "line" series with a single data point in it. For a single data point the line won't get drawn - but the axis will be displayed.